# Tricky Selector casperjs hidden div

Tags: javascript, forms, selector, casperjs

i have a, in my opinion really tricky form. The form changes div's, hidden fields & id's on every reload. and i cant find a pattern how it changes.

here's an example for the class .box.box500:

```
    <div class="box box500" style="float:left;display:none;">
<span class="errorText"></span>
<br>
<input id="czoyNToiaWhfYlNEaDg0ZGNkVi00bUxtckxLZ2cuLiI7" type="text" name="czoyNToiaWhfYlNEaDg0ZGNkVi00bUxtckxLZ2cuLiI7" value="">
</div>
<div id="boxFirma" style="display: none;margin-top: 20px;">
<div class="" style="float:left;left;margin-left:10px;display:none;">
<a name="personal"></a>
<div style="overflow:hidden; margin-top: 20px;">
<div class="box box500 " style="display:none;">
<input id="czoyNToiaWhfYlNEaDg0ZGNkUjh3d2tOOFJFd2cuLiI7" type="text" value="" name="czoyNToiaWhfYlNEaDg0ZGNkUjh3d2tOOFJFd2cuLiI7">
<br>
<span class="errorText"></span>
</div>
<div class="box box500 " style="float: left;">
<input id="czoyNToiaWhfYlNEaDg0ZGNlVFpMRjFVWjZicEEuLiI7" type="hidden" value="" name="czoyNToiaWhfYlNEaDg0ZGNlVFpMRjFVWjZicEEuLiI7">
<input id="czoyNToiaVhxemVtUGRZOHluMkNxdE9pWEd1Y1EuLiI7" type="text" value="" name="czoyNToiaVhxemVtUGRZOHluMkNxdE9pWEd1Y1EuLiI7">
<br>
<span class="errorText"></span>
</div>
<div class="box box502 " style="float: left;margin-left: 20px;">
<input id="czoxMzoiaXgtQTNQT3VWVmprLiI7" type="text" value="" name="czoxMzoiaXgtQTNQT3VWVmprLiI7">
<br>
<span class="errorText"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

sometimes the first hidden div is there, and sometimes not. the id changes on every reload. The hidden input is sometimes the first child, sometimes the second.also the div, sometimes on the frist positionen sometimes on the second. i've really no idea how to identify the input fields.

is it maybe possible to select a input filed like:

```
this.sendKeys('.box.box500:nth-child(2):style="float: left;" > input:nth-child(2):type="text"', 'text');
```

Comment: '.box.box512 "style=float: left;" > input type = text' is not clear. Please can you put this as a code block and explain which file this would be in? It reads as a class with an inline style currently.

Comment: ok, i have updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is working:

```
this.sendKeys('div.box.box500:not([style*="none"]) input[type="text"]', ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use the selector:

```
this.sendKeys('div.box.box500 input[type="text"]:not([style*="display: none"])', ...);
```

I believe this would find all of the specific inputs type="text" regardless of the order on the page.

Comment: Some of them are sometimes hidden.

Comment: Please see my edit. I have tried this on similar code and it works for me :)

Comment: Cool.  I try that later. THX.

Comment: hmmm...nearly working, but i have 3 of these box500... i have updated my initial code